# Ajuste de width para ocupar espaço que falta ser ocupado numa div

Tags: html, css

Supondo que tenho essa estrutura:

```
<div style="width:1000px">
    <div id="div1" style=""></div>
    <div id="div2" style="width:300px"></div>
</div>
```

Como fazer com que a div1 ocupe exatamente o espaço restante (700px) ?

De preferência levando em consideração já possiveis margens da div1 e div2.

A principio gostaria de fazer isso com CSS apenas, mas se não houver solução pode ser via javascript/jquery.

OBS: Não posso adicionar elementos html extras. A div2 possui width fixa.

OBS2: O cenário real é uma celula de Tabela. Nessa celula tenho o campo input que seria a "div1" no meu exemplo. E uma pequena imagem de lupa ao lado, que seria a div2 com tamanho fixo. Quero que esses dois elementos se encaixem para ocupar toda o espaço da celula

Comment: Se usar % em vez de px resolves esses problemas

Comment: Adicionei observações @CesarMiguel

Comment: @JoaoPaulo muito provavelmente você terá problema de resolução em telas não convencionais (smartphones e outros). O [Bootstrap](getbootstrap.com) pode ajudá-lo a resolver esse e outros problema futuros. Dependendo do que você está fazendo, vale a pena pensar em utilizá-lo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, você deve permitir que as duas divs ocupem a mesma linha. Para tal use o `display: inline-block`. Depois precisa remover o espaço entre as divs. Note o seguinte:

```
<div id="div1">Conteúdo 1</div>
<div id="div2">Conteúdo 2</div>
```

Existe uma quebra de linha e espaços entre `</div>` e `<div>`. Infelizmente eles farão diferença no layout. O processamento do HTML colapsa múltiplos espaços em um espaço só, mas ele não deixa de existir. Será inserido entre as duas divs o caractere `" "`. Alguns pixels de separação que vão ficar visíveis. Pode contornar assim:

```
<div id="div1">Conteúdo 1
</div><div id="div2">Conteúdo 2
</div>
```

Feio, mas funciona. Depois, aplique o `width` que quer na segunda div e na primeira use o seguinte:

```
width: calc(100% - 200px);
```

Ou seja, o tamanho total do contêiner menos o tamanho da segunda div. Note que o espaço ao redor do operador `-` é importante, não remova.

Exemplo final funcionando: **http://jsfiddle.net/Ggzkb/**

Comment: eu não entendi qual o problema da quebra de linha.

Comment: @FelipeStoker melhorei o texto

Comment: pra você ver como esse site e essencial na vida de quem esta começando, pergunta de 2014 me ajudando depois de 4 anos, obrigado @Guilherme