# Por que essas divs não ficam alinhadas?

Tags: html, css

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```css
    .content-all{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;

        background-color: yellow;
    }

    .content-descriptions{
        height:120px;
        width: 1020px;  
      
        background-color: green;
    }

    .content-descriptions-left {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 500px;
        margin: 20px;
        height: 80px;

        font-size: 14px;

        background-color:red;
    }

    .content-descriptions-right {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 400px;
        margin: 20px;
        height: 80px;

        font-size: 14px;

        background-color: blue;
    }
```

```html
<div class="content-all">

    <div class="content-descriptions">

        <div class="content-descriptions-left">
            BR huehue...
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </div>

        <div class="content-descriptions-right">
            Comossomo:<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="0" name="opcoes" /> X<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="0" name="opcoes" /> Y
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Por que as `divs` não ficam alinhadas?

Resultado obtido:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado desejado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que a div vermelha está abaixo da div azul, mas eu gostaria que elas ficassem da mesma altura, usando de preferencia a div azul como referencia.

Comment: perceba que a div vermelha está abaixo da div azul, mas eu gostaria que elas ficassem da mesma altura, usando de preferencia a div azul como referencia.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acho que é isso. Provavelmente o melhor seja usar padding no elemento de cima.

Comment: editei a pergunta pra ficar mais clara, mas as respostas já resolvem direitinho..

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento na verdade nem seria baseline, seria bottom provavelmente. mas o padding é melhor.

Comment: Realmente, por isso falei do padding. Aí você trata tudo como block, e não desalinha. Tratar bloco como texto sempre tem efeito colateral.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento como é um problema bem específico, não ia adiantar por muito mais informação não. Mesmo na 1a versão dela eu ja tinha dado o +1. Acho que está bem explicado.

Comment: @Bacco a valeu nem era pelo +1, era mais pela critica da sua "ótica", tipo algo que sobrou, faltou ou errado, mas é o que você disse mesmo, não adiantar por muito mais informação, obrigado =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem elementos `block` e `inline`, ao usar `display: inline-block` você cria umm block que fica em uma linha, portanto efeitos de "texto" como espaçamentos e alinhamentos irão afetar os divs.

Sendo "inline" você pode aplicar o `vertical-align` assim:

```css
.content-all{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    background-color: yellow;
}

.content-descriptions{
    height:120px;
    width: 1020px;  
    background-color: green;
}

.content-descriptions-left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 20px;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color:red;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.content-descriptions-right {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 20px;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 14px;

    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-all">
    <div class="content-descriptions">
        <div class="content-descriptions-left">
            BR huehue...
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </div>

        <div class="content-descriptions-right">
            Comossomo:<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="0" name="opcoes" /> X<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="0" name="opcoes" /> Y
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notei que você usou a altura fixa `height: 80px;`, mas se necessitar fazer alturas iguais e que aumentem conforme o conteúdo eu recomendo esta leitura:

- [Ajuste de width para ocupar espaço que falta ser ocupado numa div](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25838/3635)

O `display: inline-block` pode dar alguma dor de cabeça, pois como eu citei ele é afetado pelas propriedades de texto, você pode usar sim ele pra criar colunas, mas se houver qualquer propriedade de CSS pra texto como `text-align` as colunas serão afetadas, neste caso você pode usar o `float` e o `clear: both` (principalmente se quiser que o elemento pai aumente a altura conforme os elementos filhos), por exemplo:

> é necessário o pseudo `:after` no elemento "pai" pra aplicar o `clear: both`, pois os elementos `float` afetam o elemento "pai" por estarem "flutuando" (não confundir com `position: absolute`) e assim o pai não detecta mais a altura

```css
.content-all{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.content-descriptions {
    width: 1020px;
    background-color: green;
}
.content-descriptions:after {
    content: "";
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    display: block;
}

.content-descriptions-left, .content-descriptions-right {
    margin: 20px;
    height: 80px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.content-descriptions-left {
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    background-color:red;
}

.content-descriptions-right {
    float: right;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-all">
    <div class="content-descriptions">
        <div class="content-descriptions-left">
            BR huehue...
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </div>

        <div class="content-descriptions-right">
            Comossomo:<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="0" name="opcoes" /> X<br/>
            <input type="radio" value="0" name="opcoes" /> Y
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

O `float` mantem os elementos como `block` e diferente do `inline-block` as propriedades CSS pra texto (como `text-align`) não irão afeta-los. O `float` funciona justamente pra flutuar (não confundir com `position: absolute`), é como se ele procurasse espaços e tenta se mover se baseando no elemento pai e irmãos. Ou seja `float: left` ele vai tentar se mover pra esquerda até não encontrar mais "espaço". No momento que move com `float` isso afeta os "irmãos próximos" "arrastando" eles junto.

Quando no exemplo movi um elemento pra `left` com `float` e outro pra `right` é como se eles ficassem flutuantes e param de deixar de ter a quebra em quanto houver espaço, se a largura do pai for menor que os elementos flutuantes esses elementos irão quebrar.

Pode usar o `display: inline-block`, mas se sentir dificuldades com propriedades de texto CSS que afetam então talvez possa experimentar o `float`.

Comment: Muito bem explicado e funcionando perfeitamente! Muito obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues editei a resposta agora =)

Comment: Boa!! One Like!=)

Answer (score 2):

```
  .content-all{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;

        background-color: yellow;
    }

    .content-descriptions{
        height:120px;
        width: 1020px;  

        background-color: green;
    }

    .content-descriptions-left {
        float:left;
        width: 500px;
        margin: 20px;
        height: 80px;

        font-size: 14px;

        background-color:red;
    }

    .content-descriptions-right {
            float:left;
        width: 400px;
        margin: 20px;
        height: 80px;

        font-size: 14px;

        background-color: blue;
    }
```

Use o float:left para alinhar os dois.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta @Jose-Francisco funcionou perfeitamente, mas você poderia falar um pouquinho mais sobre o motivo de não ter funcionado antes e porque usando `floag:left` passou a funcionar?

Comment: Perfeito Guilherme, grato pela explicação.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues float mantem os elementos como `block` e diferente do inline-block propriedades css pra texto não irão afeta-los. O float funciona justamente pra flutuar (não confundir com position), é como se ele procurasse espaços e tenta se mover se baseando no elemento pai e irmãos. Ou seja `float: left` ele vai tentar se mover pra esquerda até não encontrar mais "espaço". No momento que move com float isso afeta os "irmãos proximos" e trás ela junto com o div especifico...

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues ... quando moveu um pra left e outro pra right é como se eles ficassem flutuantes e param de deixar de ter a quebra em quanto houver espaço.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento espetacular explicação! Muito obrigado.

Comment: Então acredito que usar `float:left` seja a melhor opção, correto @GuilhermeNascimento ?